# IAM permission denied while trying to detect intent on dialogflow CX

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-cx

I created the service account and i provided to my env following this guide

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/setup#windows

I tried to run my code using `firebase serve`, but i got the following error:

`Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/botDialogflowCX/locations/us-central1/agents/chat' denied`

I'm sure that the service account is correct. I already tried to create a dialogflow admin account, client and project owner account.

Here is my code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { SessionsClient } = require("@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx");
const crededentials = require("../../.env/botdialogflowcx-5e936a89c163.json");

exports.teste = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });


    const client = new SessionsClient({
        apiEndpoint: "us-central1-dialogflow.googleapis.com",
    });

    const sessionId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    const sessionPath = client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
        "botDialogflowCX",
        "us-central1",
        "chat",
        sessionId);
    
    console.info(sessionPath);

    const requestDialogflow = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: "Oi",
            },
            languageCode: "pt-br",
        },
    };

    client.detectIntent(requestDialogflow).then((snapshot) => {
        const webhookResponse = {
            fulfillment_response: {
                messages: [{
                    text: {
                        text: ["testandoooo", snapshot],
                    },
                },
                ],
            },
        };
    
        response.send(webhookResponse);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

I really don't know what is going on.

Running the command

`gcloud projects get-iam-policy botdialogflowcx --flatten="bindings[].members" --format="table(bindings.role)" --filter="bindings.members:teste-889@botdialogflowcx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"`

The output was `roles/dialogflow.admin`.

I add the email to the service account in the dialogflow CX - agent - share.

[email in the dialogflow CX - agent - share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkZOm.png)

[email in the account service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S030.png)

But still having the same error, that the IAM does not have permission.

Comment: 1) Lookup the **client_emil** in **botdialogflowcx-5e936a89c163.json**. 2) Edit your question and include this command and output in your question: **gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT --flatten="bindings[].members" --format="table(bindings.role)" --filter="bindings.members:$SA_EMAIL"**

Comment: Execute this command then wait five minutes and try again: **gcloud services enable dialogflow.googleapis.com**

Comment: Also try changing the client code: **const client = new SessionsClient({keyFilename: "../../.env/botdialogflowcx-5e936a89c163.json", apiEndpoint: "us-central1-dialogflow.googleapis.com"});**

Comment: Still having the same problem. I did the **gcloud services enable** and change the **keyFilename**

Comment: In the Dialogflow CX Console, does the service account have permission? https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/cx/projects The service account will need the Dialogflow agent role **Admin**. Agent Settings -> Share.

Comment: The service that you added in your last update is a different service account.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to say that i created the service account again and repeat all the steps just to have sure that i'm doing (amost) everything right.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have run out of ideas to check for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IAM Permission denied error usually occurs because the service account you are using has not been granted sufficient permission to perform the requested action on the GCP Project connected to the Dialogflow Agent, you have used the incorrect credentials in your request, or you have queried the incorrect agent.

Looking at the following code and error encountered, it seems that the Project Name and Agent Name were used instead of the Project ID and Agent ID value respectively.

```
const sessionPath = client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
        "botDialogflowCX", // update to Project ID
        "us-central1",
        "Chat", // update to Agent ID
        sessionId);
```

Please note that Project ID and Agent ID are different from the Project Name and Agent Name, you can refer to the following documentation on [how to collect IDs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api#ids).

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I just had to change the

```
client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
        "botDialogflowCX",
        "us-central1",
        "chat",
        sessionId);
```

to

```
    const sessionPath = client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
        "botdialogflowcx",
        "us-central1",
        "e55b9ef5-d1f2-4e5c-9e95-974501233d50",
        sessionId);
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running this code in cloud functions i don't believe you need to provide the credentials. If you're running this locally you would set your credentials like this :

`$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_PATH"`

That way you wouldn't need to provide the credentials in your code.

Comment: I'm receveing a error when i try to upload to cloud functions. When i try to run locally, i got the error 7.