# Dialogflow API Permission Issue on EC2: Service Account Key and Roles Confirmed

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, next.js, amazon-ec2, dialogflow-es

**Question**:
I'm encountering permission issues when attempting to make Dialogflow API calls from my Node.js(NestJs) application deployed on an EC2 instance. Notably, the service account key and roles have been confirmed to be the same as in my local environment, where the API calls are successful.

**Details**:
I'm using the Dialogflow Node.js client library in my project.
The service account key has Dialogflow Admin API and Owner roles assigned.
Other Google Cloud services (e.g., Speech to Text) work correctly with the same service account key on the EC2 instance.
The EC2 instance has internet access, and there are no apparent network issues.
The API calls are successful on my local machine, but I'm receiving permission errors on the EC2 instance.
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is already set.

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken**:

- Confirmed the correct Dialogflow API version in my Node.js project.
- Explicitly set the credentials path in my code.
- Tried recreating service account key

**Error Message**:

```
    Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/cropsea-xseb/agent' denied.
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at callErrorFromStatus (/var/app/current/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/app/current/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/app/current/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/app/current/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at /var/app/current/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:99:78
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]: for call at
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/var/app/current/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:32)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at /var/app/current/node_modules/@google-cloud/dialogflow/build/src/v2/sessions_client.js:241:29
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at /var/app/current/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at repeat (/var/app/current/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:80:25)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at /var/app/current/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:118:13
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at OngoingCallPromise.call (/var/app/current/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at NormalApiCaller.call (/var/app/current/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at /var/app/current/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:84:30
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:  code: 7,
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:  details: "IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/cropsea-xseb/agent' denied.",
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:  metadata: Metadata {
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    internalRepr: Map(2) {
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:      'endpoint-load-metrics-bin' => [Array],
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:      'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array]
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    },
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:    options: {}
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:  },
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]:  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
Dec  2 15:03:16 ip-172-31-3-220 web[36519]: } 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/cropsea-xseb/agent' denied. {"code":7,"details":"IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/cropsea-xseb/agent' denied.","metadata":{"endpoint-load-metrics-bin":[{"type":"Buffer","data":[49,215,148,34,241,30,74,31,64,57,48,169,63,59,54,89,185,63,73,182,174,237,235,80,251,189,63]}],"grpc-server-stats-bin":[{"type":"Buffer","data":[0,0,130,48,50,18,0,0,0,0]}]},"note":"Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"}
```

Code Snippet:

```
try {
  let sessionId = await this.getSessionId(userId);
  if (!sessionId) {
    sessionId = uuid();
    // Save sessionId to DB
    await this.saveSessionId(userId, sessionId as string);
  }

  const sessionPath = this.sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(
    process.env.PROJECT_ID as string,
    sessionId as string,
  );

  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: text,
        languageCode: defaultLocale, // Adjust as needed
      },
    },
  };

  const [response] = await this.sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
```

Request:
I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps to identify and resolve the permission issue when making Dialogflow API calls on my EC2 instance.

Comment: Your post does not show how you are initializing `sessionClient`. Review this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68749649/8016720) for ideas.

Comment: Review how you are setting up session path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68761649/8016720

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've done a thorough job investigating the issue. Here are some additional troubleshooting steps and suggestions that might help you identify and resolve the permission problem:

Check IAM Permissions:

Double-check that the IAM role associated with your EC2 instance has the necessary permissions for Dialogflow. Ensure that the roles assigned to your service account on the EC2 instance are identical to the ones on your local machine.
Confirm that the IAM role has the roles/dialogflow.admin and roles/dialogflow.reader roles.
Verify Environment Variables:

Confirm that the environment variables, especially GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and PROJECT_ID, are correctly set on your EC2 instance. You can print these values to the console to ensure they are being picked up by your Node.js application.
Service Account Key:

Make sure that the service account key file used on your EC2 instance is the correct one. Confirm that the file is accessible, and its contents match the expected service account configuration.
Check Firewall Rules:

Ensure that there are no network restrictions or firewall rules on the EC2 instance that might be blocking outgoing requests to the Dialogflow API. If your instance is in a VPC, check its security group settings.
Test API Access:

You can use tools like curl or Postman on your EC2 instance to manually make requests to the Dialogflow API. This can help isolate whether the issue is specific to your Node.js application or if it's a broader network or IAM issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I have already tried most of the troubleshooting steps you mentioned. It doesn't seem that there are issues with the EC2 IAM role or, firewall rules as other requests to Google services eg. Google Speech to text is working fine from the same EC2 instance using the same PROJECT_ID and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS